# Confidence interval to estimate the quality of a set of observations by matching - nonmatching ratio of second observations

Tags: statistical-significance

I'll ask my question as if it was a school assignment.

John makes 400 observations. These observations can be of 5 types: A, B, C, D, or E.

```
    observation 1:   A
    observation 2:   E
    observation 3:   A
    observation 4:   D
    observation 5:   C
    observation 6:   A
    observation 7:   B
    ....
    observation 399: A
    observation 400: E
```

Marie re-makes 45 randomly chosen of the 400 observations. 38 of them match John's observations and 7 of them do not match John's observations.

In other words, 15% of all Marie's observations do not match John's observations. What is the 95% confidence interval of this percentage ?

Let's assume the answer is:  5% - 25% (or 15% ± 10%)

Does it mean that if 40% of John's observations are "A", I'm actually sure at 95% that there is between 40+40*0.1 (=44%) and 40-40*0.1 (=36%) of observations that really are of type A?

Comment: Where does 0.1 come from in your formula? Half of the width of the 5-25% interval?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans Yes, 0.1 comes from the "distance" between the percentage found (15%) and any boundary of the confidence interval. But my calculations are certainly wrong !  I'll add this precision in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, I am a bit confused by what you are trying to do at the end but I am pretty confident that the answer is negative regardless. Several reasons for that:

- You are neglecting errors/uncertainty in Marie's observations. You cannot directly conclude from a percentage of agreement (or a confidence interval on this percentage) that all the relevant observations (and only those) are actually correct.
- There are some serious assumptions hidden in there. For example, if misclassifications are not random or independent and Marie is more likely to miss observations that were also misclassified by John, you cannot simply go from a percentage of agreement to any conclusion about the rate of errors of either of them.
- All this seems unrelated to what a confidence interval is. For starters, “sure at 95%” has no precise meaning in frequentist statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how can I have any idea of how good are my observations ? Isn't there really no way to do such a thing ? If Marie's and John's observations do not match more than 20% of the cases (what is expected if everything is random), my observations are obviously of less good quality than if both observations match at 100%.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you have a two-way table for the 45 cases studied by both people. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability for an approach common in several fields.

Comment: That's basically what psychometric reliability is about. You need some assumptions to make it tractable at all and even then, it's not that easy. In practice, people are often content to check if the rate of agreement is “high enough” and do not try to put a confidence interval around it or work out what it means quantitatively.